# How to break in this situation

Tags: python, function, loops, infinite-loop, break

So I am almost done making a Hangman Program (just the framework), but I am having trouble with breaking a loop. This is because I am supposed to allow the user to have unlimited trials, so I couldn't use something like:

```
x = 10
while x != 0
   do something
   x -= 1
```

However, I figured out another way - to make a guess_list that contains every single letter that is tried and say:

```
if final_letter in guess_list:
break
```

I thought this would work fine (and it did for a couple trials), but I just checked the program again and it didn't work (I'll insert a picture here to show the details).
[image]

The thing I've noticed here is that I need to type everything in order (if 'friend'; 'f' then 'r' then 'i'...) to get the while loop break. How can I possibly get it to break when there are no more asterisks left??

**My code is:**

```
fr = input("What file would you like to open: ")
f = open(fr, 'r')
text = f.read()
x = 0
textsplit = text.split()
guess_list = ''




import random
rand_letter = random.choice(textsplit)

for letter in range(len(textsplit)):
    final_letter = rand_letter.lower()
final_letter = ''.join(x for x in final_letter if x.isalpha())
    
for i in range(len(final_letter)):
    print ('*', end = '')
print ()
while x == 0:
    guess = input("Guess a character: ")
    guess_list += guess
    if guess not in final_letter:
         for char in final_letter:   
            if char in guess_list:
                print (char, end = ''),

            if char not in guess_list:
                print('*', end = '')
         print('')
         print("Incorrect. Try again!")
    else:
        for char in final_letter:   
            if char in guess_list:
                print (char, end = ''),

            if char not in guess_list:
                print('*', end = '')
    if final_letter in guess_list:
        print('')
        print('YOU GOT IT!!!! NIICEE')
        break
```

Any help/comment/advice/thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, reading a file in for sample words is hard to replicate. Here, I've just used a predetermined list and split it into words.

Next, I've used sets here, as sets are useful for checking if something's already been guessed or if a character is in the goal word. Also, variable names are changed for clarity's sake, final_letter being a prime example.

If someone guesses a word which has characters that are only partially in the goal word (guessing "if" for "fond"), this will add to current progress but report incorrect. If you want to make sure that characters are in order for words ("niw" not being a valid guess for "win"), this will require some changes*.

`s.update(iterable)` adds all the things in an iterable (list, set, generator, etc) to a set s. `s.issubset(other_set)` checks that all elements of s are in other_set.

```py
import random
textsplit = "friend win lose hangman".split()
guesses = set()
goal_word = random.choice(textsplit)
goal_set = set(goal_word)
print("".join(["*" for _ in goal_word]))
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a character: ")
    set_guess = set(guess)
    if set_guess.issubset(guesses):
        print("Please try again; you already guessed", guess)
        continue
    guesses.update(list(guess))
    if goal_set.issubset(guesses):
        print('YOU GOT IT!!!! NIICEE')
        break
    progress = ""
    for c in goal_word:
        if c in guesses:
            progress += c
        else:
            progress += "*"
    print(progress)
    if not all((c in goal_set for c in set_guess)):  
        print("Incorrect. Try again!")
```

*Sets are unordered, so s.issubset(other_set) only cares that all the elements of s are in other_set, as s and other_set both don't know their own order. To support ordering, consider checking for equality between the guessed word and the goal word.